# Accessing object inside object in laravel blade template

Tags: php, laravel-5.5, laravel-blade

This is my data

```
    {
        pk_int_curated_list_id: 1,
        vchr_list_name: "adasdasd",
        vchr_list_description: "afadfasdfasdf",
        vchr_keywords: "",
        vchr_business_ids: "2",
        fk_int_category_id: 6,
        fk_int_user_id: 1,
        int_status: 1,
        category: {
           pk_int_category_id: 6,
           vchr_category_name: "aaa",
           fk_int_category_id: 5,
           parent_category: {
                pk_int_category_id: 5,
                vchr_category_name: "vat22"
           }
        }
    }
```

How do I access `parent_category->vchr_category_name` in blade template in laravel `5.5`

I have tried `$var->category->parent_category->vchr_category_name` but i am getting error Trying to get property of non-object

**Update**

I just saw somewhere object can't have '_' underscores.

So I tried with changing `parent_category` to `parentcategory` and boom it worked.

**Solution**

Object names can't have underscores '_' .

Comment: {{ $var->category->parent_category->vchr_category_name }} this is the blade code

Comment: No i am not using any foreach to print out this.
As there is no array being used then why should I be using array ??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I have added the update in the question itself, the solution for the following is that object names cant have underscores.

So I tried with changing `parent_category` to `parentcategory` and boom it worked.